# Pass request user to modelform in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model where is save one of the groups of the user in my model.

Because user can be member of different groups i need to update the Selection field in my Form depending on the request.user.groups.all() queryset.

I tried to pass the initial variable to my form but this was ignored.

Any hint how to deal with this problem?

EDIT:

My view:

```
form = CoronaEventModelForm(request.POST or None, initial={'group': request.user.groups.all()})
```

my model:

```
 user = models.ForeignKey(curr_User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='group')
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my form:

```
class CoronaEventForm(forms.Form):
 user = forms.CharField()
 group = forms.CharField()
 title = forms.CharField()
 description = forms.CharField()
 slug = forms.SlugField()
 event_date = forms.DateField()



class CoronaEventModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = CoronaEvent
    fields = ['group', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'event_date']
```

it works with normal text fields but not with the group field.

Comment: Please include the code for your view and your form.

Comment: @Lomtrur i updated my original post. It works with normal fields but not with the groups queryset.

Comment: The code for your form is needed as well, not just how you create it.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding a init function to my form and passing the object during instantiation of the form.